# Inequality for infimum over intersection of sets

Tags: inequality, optimization, constraints

Let $f$ be a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Is the following in general true? $$\inf_{x \in A} f(x) \leq \inf_{x \in A\cap B} f(x)$$

Comment: What have you tried so fat? Can you think of a counter-example, or alternatively, what ideas do you have to show that this is true?

Comment: How are those statements any different, w.l.g you can interchange $A$ and $B$?  Short answer yes its true and infimum over a subset is always lager than a infimum over the superset.

Comment: You are right, the statements are equivalent, I'll update the question.

Comment: @DanielAdams how is it possible to prove that?

Comment: First prove that for two sets $A,B$ with $B\subseteq A \implies \inf_{x\in A} \leq \inf_{x\in B}$. Then, use this fact and $A\cap B\subseteq A$. HINT: if $M = \inf_{x\in A}f(x)$, then $M$ is a lower bound on values of $f$ over $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that for "taking values" you mean the domain of the function, otherwise the notion is not well defined in general (you may solve the problem defining orders on vectors in the sets $f(A),f(B)$ you are considering in the codomain.)

It comes straight from the definition of infimum. As in one comment is mentioned, the infimum of a (weakly) bigger set is for sure (weakly) smaller than the infimum of the other set. Since $A \cap B \subseteq A$, the claim follows.

Recall: The infimum of a set $S$ is defined as the maximum of the lower bounds of the set $A$.